# How to test Sql server 2005 queries when you have 2008 r2 installed

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have installed sql server 2008 r2 Management studio but the server has sql server 2005 database. Is there any why i can test the queries which will work on sql server 2005 that i write in sql server 2008.

I have sample queries which work in sql server 2008 but not in 2005.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp
(
    NoOfMembers int,
    AverageAge int
)
insert into #Tmp(NoOfMembers,AverageAge)       

Values((Select Count(*)NoOfMembers  From Customer where Confirmed = 1),
(Select AVG(CONVERT(int,Age)) AverageAge From Customer where Confirmed = 1)
)
select * From #Tmp
```

Any help
Thanx in advance

Comment: whts the error message? cuz this query worked fine in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @PraveenNambiar He said his query do not work in 2005, 2008 is fine.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar Yes My query works in 2008 but not in 2005.

Comment: yup...got it...see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sql 2008 management studio against a 2005 sql server without problems. If your SQL statement is fired against the database and do not work in sql 2005, the server will answer with an error message.

If you have a sql 2008 and want to test against 2005 you can set compatibility mode to 2005, that works as well.

Your posted sql statement want to use a subquery in your values part. That don't work on sql2005 and produce a error. If you need this in 2005, create a scalar function e.g. and use this instead.

EDIT:
Well if you want to insert data into a table using a sql at all without the `VALUES`statement you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp
(
    NoOfMembers int,
    AverageAge int
)

INSERT INTO #Tmp(NoOfMembers,AverageAge)       
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(CONVERT(int,Age)) 
FROM Customer WHERE Confirmed = 1

SELECT * FROM #Tmp
```

Comment: Thanx for your quick answer @YvesR I have set compatibility mode to 2005 in sql 2008 but it still run this query. How to overcome this because as you also mentioned it will not execute in sql 2005 but it still working fine in my scenario.

Comment: If i run your query on 2005 it fails, because sub select queries are not supported here, in 2008 all works fine. On 2005 you can use a scalar function instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Well this is how you can make it work on `SQL Server 2005`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp
(
    NoOfMembers int,
    AverageAge int
)

insert into #Tmp(NoOfMembers,AverageAge)       
    (Select Count(*), AVG(CONVERT(int,Age)) From Customer where Confirmed = 1)

select * From #Tmp
```

Comment: "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed." This is the error i got when running this query in sql server 2005. My question was not about work in sql server 2005 but the option to turn on 2005 compatibility in sql 2008.

Comment: i accidentally added an extra ')'...try this now...it will work...it worked on my 2005 instance.

Comment: Same error:( Sub queries not allowed in 2005. if you want this just try to declare a variable and set value of it and then insert in the table :)

Comment: its kinda strange as it working on my 2005 instance. remove the column alias and check..i have updated the answer.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar You need to remove the `VALUES` keyword to insert into a table using a `SELECT` afterwards, then it works fine.